# from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

This error occurred while calling up JSON.
I don't know why this error is happening.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at (this is JSON URL) from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Comment: does your url variable have a protocol attached?

Comment: You can't make AJAX requests (by default) from a `file:///` URL scheme. Use an HTTP server to serve your files

Answer (score 4):

The error message says it all. You are apparently accessing the page running this script with a protocol scheme other than the several supported for cross-origin requests. This would happen commonly if you are, say, executing a local file in your browser via the file:// protocol and trying to access some URL on the Internet in your `$.getJSON` call.

Comment: It's settled. Thank you!